# Why undefine failed in m4?

Tags: linux, m4

> define(foo,0000) 
>    foo 
>    0000 
>    undefine('foo') 
>    foo 
>    0000

---

thanks.
jcyang.

Comment: Er, what are you trying to say?

Comment: Please tell us some more about your problem: what are you trying to do? What language? What exactly is your problem?

Comment: @lucas,gabb0:It's a simple question on m4 macro language.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to quote `foo` with a backtick in front and a single-quote after in order to undefine it.  Otherwise, it winds up substituted and you undefine `0000`.  So:

```
undefine(`foo')
```

Comment: Thanks,it works.It is very strange => one backtick one side,one single-quote on the other side.I thought the two side were both single-quote...

Comment: Yeah, it's certainly bizarre, but that's m4 for you.

Comment: Different quote characters for left and right give you an ability to have nested quotes.  If you don't like it, you can always use `changequote` to override them with a character of your choise.